# Python Module change folder name

Tags: python, import, module, drive, file-not-found

I am in the process of transferring my data science projects from the desktop to the Cloud and find it very interesting and started working with Google Colab recently.

Currently, I am working in a notebook and I imported a Python module (.py file) with functions that I wrote. In this module, some functions state that Python should open a file from folder “data”, which was a folder on my desktop. Now I am getting the following error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/my_filename.csv'
```

What should I change in my `.py` file so that the correct CSV files will be opened? All CSV files are now transferred to Google Drive.

Comment: You have `'data'` in your Python code, but you want to access some other directory? Well, change `'data'` to `'something else'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[zvone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/389289/zvone) [is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65657435/python-module-change-folder-name/65727341#comment116085267_65657435). Actually, I did change that but found out that I repeatedly made a mistake not to include `/content/drive` in the path.

Comment: a good practice would be to make it a parameter (as a constant or a variable).